# Is process.hrtime() suitable for monitoring uptime?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to monitor the uptime and send data at high frequency on node.js server. The server will broadcast network data every few milliseconds.

But using `Date.now()` is not accurate enough. So I am thinking of using the high resolution timer `process.hrtime()`. I don't know what is the max value of `process.hrtime`. I need to run the server for at least 6 months. Will it overflow very soon?

Comment: You really need millisecond resolution of uptime? If not you can use [process.uptime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime), it will return uptime in seconds.

Comment: @ponury-kostek I am building a game server, uptime is only one of the requirements. I also need it to perform high frequency tasks at different frequencies.

Comment: So what resolution do you need?

Comment: @ponury-kostek 1ms or 500 microseconds will be accurate enough. But all I need is to maintain a incremental value long enough without overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

Primary use of `process.hrtime()` is is for measuring performance between intervals ([docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)) but it can be also used for measuring uptime with nanosecond precision.

It returns time in array `[seconds, nanoseconds]`, where `nanoseconds` are the remaining part of time not representable by whole second.

Seconds will reach max safe integer (9007199254740991) in thousands of years. Nanosecond will never reach it as the maximum nanoseconds not representable by whole second is 999999999.

Comment: I know this question is one year old, but someone might have the same question and will find this useful